# How can I attack with two weapons on the same turn?

Tags: dnd-5e, actions

So I'm a bit lost on how dual wielding works in D&D 5th edition. In chapter 6 of the PHB, page 195, *Two-Weapon Fighting* is described as below....

> When you take the Attack action and attack with a light melee weapon that you’re holding in one hand, you can use a bonus action to attack with a different light melee weapon that you’re holding in the other hand. You don’t add your ability modifier to the damage of the bonus attack, unless that modifier is negative...

As it describes you need a *Bonus Action* to attack with the other weapon. So essentially, I would be unable to dual wield weapons and attack with both on the same turn UNLESS I had a spell or ability that granted me a bonus action. Is that correct?

Also there is a *Dual Wielding* Feat (PHB page 165) that I know has a few bonuses, such as an additional +1 AC and so on. I kind of understand that, Dual Wielding is a passive ability. But I am simply lost as to if I'm capable of two weapon fighting at all.

In the end my goal is to fight people with two shortswords as a Rogue, and have a few daggers on me to throw, in pairs, at a target. This would allow me some ranged attacks, versus always being close the enemy.

Please help me, I'm really confused and lost.